# encountered "Syntax error in regex pattern" when using str_locate

Tags: r, string, web-scraping, rvest

I have problems with str_locate syntax, as follow:

```
library(stringr)
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(stringi)
library(readr)
library(readstata13)
list.mst = read.dta13("mst.dta")
list.mst = list.mst$ma_thue
link.source = 'https://infodoanhnghiep.com/tim-kiem/ma-so-thue/'
trim <- function (x) gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$", "", x)
info = c()
for (mst in list.mst) {
  link = paste0(link.source, mst,'/')
  message(link)
  search.result = read_html(link) 
  all.com.link = search.result %>% html_nodes(".company-name a") %>% html_attr('href') %>% unique()
  for (com.link in all.com.link) {
    com.page = read_html(paste0("https:",com.link))
    com.info = com.page %>% html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="left-content"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]') %>% html_text()
    com.name = str_sub(com.info, 
                       start = str_locate(com.info, pattern = "Tên doanh nghi???p:")[2]+1,
                       end = str_locate(com.info, pattern = "Mã s??? thu???:")[1]-1)
    com.mst <- str_sub(com.info, 
                       start = str_locate(com.info, pattern = "Mã s??? thu???:")[2]+1,
                       end = str_locate(com.info, pattern = "Tình tr???ng ho???t ")[1]-1)
    com.active = str_sub(com.info, 
                         start = str_locate(com.info, pattern = "Tình tr???ng ho???t ")[2]+1+5,
                         end = str_locate(com.info, pattern = "ký qu???n lý:")[1]-1-9)
    com.add = str_sub(com.info, 
                      start = str_locate(com.info, pattern = "???a ch???:")[2]+1,
                      end = str_locate(com.info, pattern = "i???n tho???i:")[1]-1-1)
    com.tel = str_sub(com.info, 
                      start = str_locate(com.info, pattern = "i???n tho???i:")[2] +1,
                      end = str_locate(com.info, pattern = "???i di???n pháp lu???t:")[1]-1-1)
    com.cap.phep = str_sub(com.info, 
                           start = str_locate(com.info, pattern = "Ngày c???p gi???y phép:")[2]+1,
                           end = str_locate(com.info, pattern = "Ngày b???t ")[1]-1)
    com.hoat.dong = str_sub(com.info, 
                            start = str_locate(com.info, pattern = "Ngày b???t ")[2]+1+14,
                            end = str_locate(com.info, pattern = "Ngày nh???n TK:")[1]-1)
    com.nganh2 =     str_sub(com.info, 
                             start = str_locate(com.info, pattern = "Ngành ngh??? kinh doanh:")[2])
    com.nganh = str_sub(com.info, 
                        start = str_locate(com.info, pattern = "Ngành ngh??? kinh doanh:")[2] +1)
    info= rbind(info, t(c(com.name, com.mst, com.active, com.add, com.tel, com.cap.phep, com.hoat.dong,com.nganh)))
    info = trim(info)
  }
}

https://infodoanhnghiep.com/tim-kiem/ma-so-thue/0100111338/
Error in stri_locate_first_regex(string, pattern, opts_regex = opts(pattern)) : 
Syntax error in regex pattern. (U_REGEX_RULE_SYNTAX, context=`//TÃªn doanh nghi???p:`)
```

Here is my sample dataset : [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jc2eio5u075aweo/mst.dta?dl=0)

I really don't know what's problem with my codes, so I really appreciate any suggestions for me. upom seeing that the Vietnamese phrases were not read properly by R, I've tried to escape it but to no avail. Thanks all!!!!

Comment: What are you trying to scrape on that site?

Comment: Welcome to SO!  While it's perfectly fine to answer your own question, please keep the answer section **only** for working answers, you can reply to comments through comments. Regarding yout error you seem to have some kind of encoding issue, `str_locate("Tên doanh nghiệp: CÔNG TY CỔ PHẦN MỸ THUẬT TRUNG ƯƠNG", fixed("Tên doanh nghiệp:"))` forks fine for me (both with and without `fixed()` ). What is the version of RStudio you are using and what's the default file encoding (tools -> global options -> code -> saving)?

Comment: Once the character ecnoding issue gets sorted, that parsing flow itself can't work as your `com.info` includes a paragraph above the table and not the table itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in comments, that particular error seems to be triggered by some kind of character encoding issue, and there's not enough information to reproduce or debug this.

*BUT* there's really no need to solve this through substrings as each of those descriptions and values is placed in its own element. As number of rows in those tables can vary, missing values will introduce `NA` values in resulting dataset.

The example bellow replaces the inner loop  in question and uses fixed set of URLs as an example; value descriptions are taken from the first column of the table and then cleaned with *janitor*.

```r
library(rvest)
library(purrr)
library(janitor)
all.com.link_example <- c("https://infodoanhnghiep.com/thong-tin/Cong-Ty-Co-Phan-My-Thuat-Trung-uong-11338.html",
                          "https://infodoanhnghiep.com/thong-tin/Cong-ty-TNHH-hoi-cho-trien-lam-quoc-te-Thang-Long-11338-003.html",
                          "https://infodoanhnghiep.com/thong-tin/Chi-Nhanh-Cty-My-Thuat-TW-11338-001.html")

info <- map(all.com.link_example,
    \(url) {
      html <- read_html(url)
      info <- html_element(html, ".company-info .description") %>% html_text2()
      # each cell in the 2-column table
      html_elements(html, ".mt-20 .responsive-table-cell") %>% 
      html_text2() %>% 
      # as 2-coumn matrix, same shape and structure as table
      matrix(ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE) %>% 
      # add infor row to matrix
      rbind(c("info", info))
      }) %>% 
  # m[,1] - description column 
  # m[,2] - value column
  # make safe column names from 2nd column, apply those to values vector
  # map_dfr turns each such list into tibble row retunrs single tribble
  map_dfr(\(m) set_names(m[,2], make_clean_names(m[,1])))
```

Result:

```r
info
#> # A tibble: 3 × 17
#>   ten_doanh_ng…¹ ten_g…² ma_so…³ tinh_…⁴ noi_d…⁵ dia_chi dien_…⁶ dai_d…⁷ giam_…⁸
#>   <chr>          <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  
#> 1 CÔNG TY CỔ PH… CEFINA… 010011… Đang h… Cục Th… Số 66,… 043844… "\r Ng… Cao Ho…
#> 2 Công ty TNHH … <NA>    010011… Doanh … Cục Th… Số 1 G… <NA>    "\r Võ… Võ Viế…
#> 3 Chi Nhánh Cty… <NA>    010011… Doanh … Cục Th… 371/13… <NA>    "\r Đi… Chu Vă…
#> # … with 8 more variables: ngay_cap_giay_phep <chr>,
#> #   ngay_bat_dau_hoat_dong <chr>, ngay_nhan_tk <chr>, nam_tai_chinh <chr>,
#> #   so_lao_dong <chr>, cap_chuong_loai_khoan <chr>, tk_ngan_hang <chr>,
#> #   info <chr>, and abbreviated variable names ¹​ten_doanh_nghiep,
#> #   ²​ten_giao_dich, ³​ma_so_thue, ⁴​tinh_trang_hoat_dong, ⁵​noi_dang_ky_quan_ly,
#> #   ⁶​dien_thoai, ⁷​dai_dien_phap_luat, ⁸​giam_doc

tibble::glimpse(info)
#> Rows: 3
#> Columns: 17
#> $ ten_doanh_nghiep       <chr> "CÔNG TY CỔ PHẦN MỸ THUẬT TRUNG ƯƠNG", "Công ty…
#> $ ten_giao_dich          <chr> "CEFINAR., JSC", NA, NA
#> $ ma_so_thue             <chr> "0100111338", "0100111338-003", "0100111338-001"
#> $ tinh_trang_hoat_dong   <chr> "Đang hoạt động (đã được cấp GCN ĐKT)", "Doanh …
#> $ noi_dang_ky_quan_ly    <chr> "Cục Thuế Thành phố Hà Nội", "Cục Thuế Thành ph…
#> $ dia_chi                <chr> "Số 66, ngõ Núi Trúc, phố Núi Trúc, Phường Kim …
#> $ dien_thoai             <chr> "0438444555", NA, NA
#> $ dai_dien_phap_luat     <chr> "\r Nguyễn Minh Vũ\r", "\r Võ Viết Lượng\r", "\…
#> $ giam_doc               <chr> "Cao Hoàng Dương", "Võ Viết Lượng", "Chu Văn Hả…
#> $ ngay_cap_giay_phep     <chr> "22/05/1998", "08/04/2002", "21/12/1998"
#> $ ngay_bat_dau_hoat_dong <chr> "10/03/1993", "01/01/2002", "31/05/1993"
#> $ ngay_nhan_tk           <chr> "15/03/2004", "02/04/2002", "28/05/1998"
#> $ nam_tai_chinh          <chr> "2000", "2002", "1998"
#> $ so_lao_dong            <chr> "107", "10", "5"
#> $ cap_chuong_loai_khoan  <chr> "025-194", "1-025-550-554", "1-025-430-459"
#> $ tk_ngan_hang           <chr> "\r Mã số thuế: 0100111338\nTên giao dịch: CEFI…
#> $ info                   <chr> "\r\n\nCông Ty Cổ Phần Mỹ Thuật Trung Ương có m…
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>